# React createSlice's extraReducers's state access

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

i have the following code:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { client } from '../../api/client';

const initialState = {
    logBook: [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: null
};

export const logNewEntry = createAsyncThunk(
    'logBook/addNewEntry', 
    async (logEntry) => {
        const response = await client.post('/testPost', logEntry);
        console.log('post done');
        return response.data;
    }
);

const logBookSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'logBook',
  initialState,
  // non async calls
  reducers: {},
  },
  // async calls
  extraReducers: {
    [logNewEntry.fulfilled] : (state, action) => {
        console.log('add to list');
        console.log(state);
        console.log(action);
        state.logBook.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
})

//export const {resetName} = logBookSlice.actions;
export default logBookSlice.reducer;

export const selectLogBook = (state) => state.logBook.logBook;
```

the `console.log(state);` is not referencing the state of the logBook and therefor I can't add the new entry to it. What console prints:

```
Proxy {i: 0, A: {…}, P: false, I: false, D: {…}, …}
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true
```

I used the reduc template's counterSlice as an example to build this, and their works.

```
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    },
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux Toolkit uses Immer inside of `createSlice`.  Immer wraps your original data in a Proxy object so it can track attempted "mutations".

Unfortunately, this does make logging draft state difficult, because browsers show Proxies in a mostly unreadable format.

The line `state.logbook.push(action.payload)` should be valid as-is.  However, if you want to log the data more readably, you can use the Immer `current` method that we export from RTK, which converts the Proxy-wrapped data back to a plain JS object:

```js
console.log(current(state))
```

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current .

Comment: thanks, so my code works, just didn't like the data being pushed into the array.
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {date, time, unixTimestamp})

Comment: That's not a Redux thing, that's an issue with how you're rendering in your React component. React won't let you do `<div>{someObject}</div>`.  You can only pass primitive values as the variables in JSX output, like `<div>{someObject.name}</div>`. Fixing your rendering logic will solve that error.